# Is there any dummy Bank data available online which I can use to bank a simple bank application in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, salesforce1-app, webservices

I want to integrate a bank with my salesforce. Is there any online dummy bank whose data I can use to integrate it with my salesforce.

My Requirements :-

I have a bank whose web services are available.

I have my salesforce where I will store the data from the bank in sObjects.

I will create an app in salesforce to show the tabs and objects data.

Answer (score 0):

You need the payment gateway integration for this. There are many payment gateway available Authorize.net, Paypal, Stripe, Paytm which you can use as no bank will provide you direct access to there data.

Comment: Hey @TusharSharma , I found this online openbank.apigee.io. What this open bank provide. Is it provding me the data. I didn't get what it exactly do.

Comment: @SagarPanwar is a type of payment gateway, But I am not sure about this.